# On the norm map in Milnor K-theory for $K_2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

I am currently studying Milnor $K$-theory and came across his definition of a transfer map which works if we have an inclusion of rings.

However, in Quillen's $K$-theory, he defines a transfer map for injections of rings.

My question is now: how is the norm/transfer map defined for an injection of rings? More precisely: if I have an injective ring homomorphism
\begin{equation*}
f:R\to S,
\end{equation*}how is the transfer map
\begin{equation*}
f^*:K_2(B)\to K_2(A)
\end{equation*}defined? I have read something about restriction of scalars but do not see how to apply it to a specific case if we're not talking about the category of all $R$- resp. $S$-modules.

Every reference I find just notes that is it 'well-known' and I cannot seem to construct it myself.

I'm happy about any suggestions and answers, thanks!

Comment: if you have an injection $f:A\to B$, cannot you just identify $A$ with $f(A)$ (via $f$) and thus get an inclusion $f(A)\subset B$? (I might be missing something)

Comment: Thanks for your idea! I could do that is not what I essentially want. I want a map $f^*:K_2(B)\to K_2(A)$, which does not work with yor proposed approach if $f(A)$ is not the whole $B$. I will clarify this in my post.

Comment: I mean: you already have the transfer map $K_2(B)\to K_2(f(A))$ and then you just have an iso $K_2(A)\cong K_2(f(A))$

Comment: I see, thanks! Just to make sure: how do you define the transfer map $K_2(B)\to K_2(f(A))$?

Comment: I don't :) but you wrote that Milnor does it for inclusion of rings and $f(A)\subset B$ is an inclusion of rings

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion :) Thank you!